# This moderator's name and designation are not on the same line - why not?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Take a look at [this moderator's profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli):

[image: It isn't centered vertically - take my word for it.]

As you can see, I expect "Oli" and "Moderator" to have the same [baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)), but it appears that they do not. Can this please be corrected?

**Details:**

- Chrome 15.0.874.121 m
- Windows 8 32-bit

*Note: I tried using Chrome's Incognito mode just in case a script or extension was messing things up and I could still reproduce it.*

Comment: It's not just margin, the line-height (thus the rendered height) is different too.

Comment: His diamond is very heavy! That means some community moderators are more community moderators. `;-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno: So then what about the 'less info' link? :P

Comment: Oh, I misread you. The "less info" link is there to keep company to the "moderator" part. You know, one is an alone soul, two is happy hour!

Comment: this has been fixed. it will be in the next build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding this should bring it in line with the other jobbies on that line:

```
h1#user-displayname {margin:0;line-height:40px}
```

Comment: Does that also include the "more info" link? We don't want it to be the lone star. `:-)`